# Why was default SIGPIPE handler changed?

Tags: c, pipe, signals, codeblocks

I'm working on a test and i'm asked how to make a "read" sleep or a "write" stop a process"

For the latter I don't understand why my sigpipe is, indeed raised, but isn't stopping the process:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define READING 0
#define WRITING 1
#define DESCRIPTOR_COUNT 2

void signal_handler(int signal){
    printf("sigpipe received\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    int tube[DESCRIPTOR_COUNT];
    pipe(tube);
//    signal(SIGPIPE, signal_handler);
    close(tube[READING]);

    if(write(tube[WRITING], "message", 8)<0)
        if(errno==EPIPE)
            printf("EPIPE returned\n");

    printf("123");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Without signal() (quoted)**

[image]

**With signal() (unquoted)**

[image]

SIGPIPE is indeed received, but in the case I don't handle it the process **should stop**, but since I can write "123" this means the process *wasn't stopped*.
Why?

Also I'm on Fedora 28, i'm using codeblocks 17.12.

Was SIGPIPE ignored...? Reason?

**SOLUTION ?**

```
struct sigaction action;
action.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
sigaction(SIGPIPE, &action, 0);
```

Replacing `signal()` with this will have the default behaviour as expected!

**EDIT** I've now changed the title from "SIGPIPE doesn't stop process" to "Why was default SIGPIPE handler changed?"

======================================================

**Answer**

After talking with the guys from codeblocks, codeblocks uses wxWidgets, and on linux (fedora 28 here) wxWidgets uses gtk library, as explained by Mark Plotnick in the comments, gtk changes the signal handler for SIGPIPE, since codeblocks runs codes using a fork or an exec, the code run through codeblocks is influenced by gtk library.

Comment: Hmm, works for *me*, Linux. What's the platform? Does it work with this [mcve]? If SIGPIPE is ignored, `write` will return `EPIPE`. Is that the case?

Comment: Fedora 28, and epipe isn't returned :/

Comment: I've edited my post I hope it's more clear now!

Comment: `write()==EPIPE ...` :: write returns -1 on error, and sets **errno** to EPIPE.

Comment: thanks, i've changed that, still the mystery remains on the cause of it **without signal()**

Comment: Works here as expected (no handler -->> terminated) A few notes: 1) don't call printf()  from within a signal handler 2) diagnostic output should go to stderr 3) are you running your program under a debugger (or  workbench, GUI, etc) ?

Comment: I'm using codeblocks sir

Comment: Try it from the commandline.

Comment: It works as it should **in commandline** i have no idea what codeblocks is doing...

Comment: btw I have the last version of code::blocks : ver. 17.12

Comment: Ran codeblocks under gdb. Turns out gtk library is making process ignore sigpipe, in several places. First one is https://github.com/linuxmint/gtk/blob/master/gtk/gtkmain.c#L689 . Comments say `Since 2.18, GTK+ calls signal (SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)
 during initialization, to ignore SIGPIPE signals, since these are
 almost never wanted in graphical applications. If you do need to
 handle SIGPIPE for some reason, reset the handler after gtk_init(),
 but notice that other libraries (e.g. libdbus or gvfs) might do
 similar things.` May want to file a feature request with codeblocks folks.

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour you are reporting is consistent with the Code::Blocks IDE setting, implicitly or explicitly, the SIGPIPE behaviour to SIG_IGN.  This is readily inherited.  It isn't what I'd expect — I'd expect your program to be launched with SIGPIPE (and, indeed, all other signals) set to SIG_DFL, the default signal behaviour.  If this turns out to be the problem, you have the basis for a bug report to the developers of Code::Blocks.  If it turns out not to be the problem, then we've got some hard thinking ahead to work out what actually is happening<sup>**`*`**</sup>.

You could demonstrate whether this is what's happening with Code::Blocks by paying attention to the return value from [`signal()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html), or by using [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) to interrogate the signal handling mode without modifying it.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define READING 0
#define WRITING 1
#define DESCRIPTOR_COUNT 2

static void signal_handler(int signum)
{
    // Lazy; normally, I'd format the signal number into the string, carefully
    (void)signum;
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "sigpipe received\n", sizeof("sigpipe received\n")-1);
}

int main(void)
{
    void (*handler)(int) = signal(SIGPIPE, signal_handler);

    if (handler == SIG_DFL)
        printf("old handler was SIG_DFL\n");
    else if (handler == SIG_IGN)
    {
        printf("old handler was SIG_IGN\n");
        (void)signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    }
    else
    {
        // Standard C does not allow a cast from function pointer to object pointer
        //printf("there was a non-standard handler installed (%p)\n", (void *)handler);
        printf("there was a non-standard handler installed\n");
    }

    int tube[DESCRIPTOR_COUNT];
    pipe(tube);    
    close(tube[READING]);

    if (write(tube[WRITING], "message", 8) < 0)
    {
        if (errno == EPIPE)
            printf("EPIPE returned\n");
        else
            printf("errno = %d\n", errno);
    }

    printf("123\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that the standard idiom for setting a signal handler using `signal()` in a program was:

```
if (signal(signum, SIG_IGN) != SIG_IGN)
    signal(signum, signal_handler);
```

This means that if a program was protected from signals, it stays protected.  If it was handling signals (by default, or perhaps explicitly by a prior call to `signal()`), then you install your own signal handler.  Equivalent code using `sigaction()` would be:

```
struct sigaction sa;
if (sigaction(signum, 0, &sa) == 0 && sa.sa_handler != SIG_IGN)
{
    sa.sa_handler = signal_handler;
    sa.sa_flag &= ~SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(signum, sa, 0);
}
```

(One advantage of this: the structure is initialized by the call to `sigaction()`, so there's no need to fiddle with the masks.  The tweak to the flags ensures that the basic handler, not the extended handler, is used.)

When I compile the source code (`pipe13.c`) into program `pipe13` and run it, I get:

```
$ make pipe13
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes pipe13.c -o pipe13
$ pipe13
old handler was SIG_DFL
sigpipe received
EPIPE returned
123
$ (trap '' 13; pipe13)
old handler was SIG_IGN
EPIPE returned
123
$
```

This variant uses `sigaction()` to interrogate the signal handling:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define READING 0
#define WRITING 1
#define DESCRIPTOR_COUNT 2

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    if (sigaction(SIGPIPE, 0, &sa) != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "siagaction() failed\n");
    else if (sa.sa_handler == SIG_DFL)
        printf("old handler was SIG_DFL\n");
    else if (sa.sa_handler == SIG_IGN)
        printf("old handler was SIG_IGN\n");
    else
        printf("there was a non-standard handler installed\n");

    int tube[DESCRIPTOR_COUNT];
    pipe(tube);    
    close(tube[READING]);

    if (write(tube[WRITING], "message", 8) < 0)
    {
        if (errno == EPIPE)
            printf("EPIPE returned\n");
        else
            printf("errno = %d\n", errno);
    }

    printf("123\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When run (program `pipe83`), I get:

```
$ pipe83
old handler was SIG_DFL
$ echo $?
141
$ (trap '' 13; pipe83)
old handler was SIG_IGN
EPIPE returned
123
$
```

Note that with the default signal handling, the program terminates before printing `123`.  POSIX shells encode 'child died from signal N' by reporting the exit status as `128 + N`; SIGPIPE is `13`, so `141` indicates that the shell died from a SIGPIPE signal.  (Yes, modern youngsters would probably write `(trap '' PIPE; pipe83)` and it works — such niceties weren't available when I learned shell programming.)

It would not be all that hard to generalize the code to test whether Code::Blocks sets any other signals to other than the default handling.  It can be a little fiddly, though, if you want to adapt to which signals are available on a machine.

---

<sup>**`*`**</sup> In [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185322/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-sheed), we established that the program is run in a VMware image running Fedora 28, hosted on a Windows 10 machine.  Because of this, there are enough possible places for there to be trouble that it is not clear that the problem is necessarily in Code::Blocks — it is simply not clear where the problem originates.  However, the problem does indeed seem to be that the test program is started with SIGPIPE handling set to SIG_IGN instead of SIG_DFL when it is run from Code::Blocks.

Comment: `Code::Blocks IDE setting, implicitly or explicitly, the SIGPIPE behaviour to SIG_IGN` why would codeblocks decide to change the default behaviour? Even though it's using gnu gcc which declares that the default behaviour should be to terminate the process? cf: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Operation-Error-Signals.html

Comment: I don't know — I didn't write Code::Blocks and I've not inspected the code.  But one possible reason is that Code::Blocks doesn't want to get SIGPIPE signals itself when it runs the compiler, for example, so it ignores the signal to force the `write()` system call to report `EPIPE` errors instead.  Another possibility is that Code::Blocks is launched with SIGPIPE ignored and it never changes that status. 
 Note that I only claimed "consistent with" — and provided code that would allow you (as the OP) to test whether Code::Blocks is indeed launching your program with SIGPIPE ignored.

Comment: It isn't what I expect, but it is hard to detect how Code::Blocks is launched and which signal dispositions it has when launched vs what it sets for itself (and doesn't reset for its children).  It could be a bug in Code::Blocks; it could be a bug in whatever you use to launch Code::Blocks.  I don't pontificate on why it is as it is; I'm merely offering a way to help you detect what is going on, which will give you an explanation for what you see.  If you really want to fix it, you'll write a program that resets all signals to SIG_DFL and then executes the program given as its arguments.

Comment: Thank you for your time. But I get storage size of ‘sa’ isn’t known

Comment: Then you need to activate the POSIX extensions (`#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` or `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` before the first include.  If that doesn't work, then you probably can't use `sigaction()` on your machine; use `signal()` code instead.

Comment: I was told to use those compiler settings `-Wc90-c99-compat
-ansi` it seems to be the reason for this problem (with or without your defines)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185322/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-sheed).

Answer (score 0):

[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is not a compiler, just an IDE. It (probably) runs the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler. And the GCC compiler don't matter much for signal handling. Read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) for more (calling `printf` inside a signal handler is forbidden because `printf` is not *async-signal-safe* so your `printf("sigpipe received\n");` inside a signal handler is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). Signal handling is done mostly by the [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) (see its source code on [kernel.org](https://kernel.org/)) with a small bit of it handled by your C standard library, probably [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/).

> It seems codeblocks changes the default signal handler for SIGPIPE

This is very unlikely (and almost certainly false). You could use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on your program to understand what system calls it is doing.

> ```
>   printf("123");
> ```

You forgot a `\n`. Remember that `stdout` is usually line-buffered. Or you should call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html).

When you run a program from inside Code::Blocks it could run without a terminal. I strongly recommend running your program inside a [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) (see [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html) and [pty(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html)). The C standard library is permitted to use something like [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) to behave differently when `stdout` is or is not a tty (in particular, buffering is done differently, see [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html)). Read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) and [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html).

You could also try to run your program by redirecting its stdin, stdout, stderr to a file or a pipe (perhaps using `|& cat` or `|& less` with `bash` or `zsh`), or anything which is not a tty.

BTW, [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). You can study its source code to understand what it is doing.

Consider also using [stdbuf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stdbuf.1.html) to run your program with different buffering operations.

Comment: As you said it's using gcc compiler, the thing is in **commandline** SIGPIPE stops the process, "123" is not printed, using "compile and build" in codeblocks gives me a different behaviour, it means codeblocks is doing something

Comment: I'm sure that the file I'm compiling in commandline is the *exact same file* i'm using on codeblocks, I've even "clean" and re"build" my file *on codeblocks*, i've checked in commandline the file i was compiling with `cat main.c` it's the same one.

Comment: Sir i've read you but the heart of the matter is not whether `printf()` is printing on the right stream, the instruction `printf()` is _after the instruction_ `write()` , it shouldn't even be processed.